# Scrolling a div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to create a div in a container within a container which is scrollable with up and down arrows in jQuery.

The only thing I can find which I wish to use was
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex11/scrollc2.htm

I would've started attempting to convert that to jQuery, however it apepars to use tags like ilayer and layer. I would like to use more standard tags if possible.

Any pointers in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Particularly for dynamic height would be good.  I need this as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I would like to use ScrollTo jQuery Plugin however I cannot actually get it to work. It is lacking a simple example - which is all I need!

Answer (score 25):

I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but did you know you can use the CSS `overflow` property to create scrollbars?

CSS:

```
div.box{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  All your text content...
</div>
```

Comment: I think what the OP wanted to do, though, is replace this functionality with jQuery. Actually, I would probably set the CSS overflow to auto. No need for scrollbars if the content isn't longer than the div. This should actually be the default CSS for the DIV. javascript should be used to turn off overflow.

Comment: You solved a very big problem of mine with this code. I want some little more help. How can I change color or format of these scroll bars of div?

Answer (score 10):

An excellent plug-in is [jscrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)

Comment: This is absolutely beautiful. I integrated it into a site within minutes. Amazing Job !!!!

Answer (score 7):

jCarousel is a Jquery Plugin , it have same functionality already implemented , which might want to archive. it's nice and easy.
[here](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/special_textscroller.html) is the link

and complete documentation can be found [here](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/)

Comment: Please describe what you have linked to, it may get you more upvotes. Thanks!

Comment: This example doesn't work in firefox 4, some others at: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Examples do.

Answer (score 7):

Relatively-position your content div within a parent div having overflow:hidden. Make your up/down arrows move the top value of the content div. The following jQuery is untested. Let me know if you require any further assistance with it as a concept.

```
div.container {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
div.content {
  position:relative;
  top:0;
}

<div class="container">
  <p>
    <a href="enablejs.html" class="up">Up</a> / 
    <a href="enablejs.html" class="dn">Down</a>
  </p>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>
</div>

$(function(){
  $(".container a.up").bind("click", function(){
    var topVal = $(this).parents(".container").find(".content").css("top");
    $(this).parents(".container").find(".content").css("top", topVal-10);
  });

  $(".container a.dn").bind("click", function(){
    var topVal = $(this).parents(".container").find(".content").css("top");
    $(this).parents(".container").find(".content").css("top", topVal+10);
  });
});
```

Comment: Why not increment and decrement `scrollTop` with a timer?

Comment: I believe you can do .css("top", "+=10px"); ?

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for this same answer and I couldn't find anything that did exactly what I wanted so I created my own and posted it here:

http://seekieran.com/2011/03/jquery-scrolling-box/

Working Demo: http://jsbin.com/azoji3

Here is the important code:

```
function ScrollDown(){

  //var topVal = $('.up').parents(".container").find(".content").css("top").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
  var topVal = $(".content").css("top").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
    topVal = parseInt(topVal);
  console.log($(".content").height()+ " " + topVal);
  if(Math.abs(topVal) < ($(".content").height() - $(".container").height() + 60)){ //This is to limit the bottom of the scrolling - add extra to compensate for issues
  $('.up').parents(".container").find(".content").stop().animate({"top":topVal - 20  + 'px'},'slow');
    if (mouseisdown)
setTimeout(ScrollDown, 400);
  }
```

Recursion to make it happen:

```
 $('.dn').mousedown(function(event) {
    mouseisdown = true;
    ScrollDown();
}).mouseup(function(event) {
    mouseisdown = false;
});
```

Thanks to Jonathan Sampson for some code to start but it didn't work initially so I have heavily modified it. Any suggestions to improve it would be great here in either the comments or comments on the blog.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is ages old, but upon searching for something similar this morning, and reading up on Atømix' response (as this is what we're aiming on achieving), I found this: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-jquery-slider-to-scroll-a-div.

Just putting that there in case anyone else needs a solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a plug-in for this if you don't want to write a bare-bones implementation yourself. It's called "scrollTo" ([link](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)). It allows you to perform programmed scrolling to certain points, or use values like `-= 10px` for continuous scrolling.

[ScrollTo jQuery Plug-in](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>scroll</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>

<style>
div.container {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
div.content {
  position:relative;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;  
  overflow:hidden;
  top:0;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <p>
    <a href="javascript:up();"><img src="/images/img_flecha_left.png" class="up" /></a>
    <a href="javascript:down();"><img src="/images/img_flecha_left.png" class="down" /></a>   

  </p>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Hello World</p><p>Hello World</p>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function up() {
    var topVal = $(".content").css("top"); //alert(topVal);
    var val=parseInt(topVal.replace("px",""));
    val=val-20;
    $(".content").css("top", val+"px");    
}
function down() {
    var topVal = $(".content").css("top"); //alert(topVal);
    var val=parseInt(topVal.replace("px",""));
    val=val+20;
    $(".content").css("top", val+"px");  
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```