# Scroll to a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll

so I have a page that has a fixed link bar on the side.  I'd like to scroll to the different divs.  Basically the page is just one long website, where I'd like to scroll to different divs using the menu box to the side.

Here is the jQuery I have so far

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contactlink').click = function() {
        $(document).scrollTo('#contact');
    }
});
```

The issue is it is automatically going to the contact div when it loads, then when I press the `#contactlink` in the menu it scrolls back to the top.

EDIT: HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <!-- jQuery-->
    <script src = "<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    
    <!-- .js file-->
    <script src = "<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/pagetwo.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/css/reset.css" />    
            
    <!-- .css for page -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/css/pagetwo.css"/>                       
    
    <!-- page title-->
    <title><!-- Insert Title --></title>
    

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    
        <div id="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li><a id = "aboutlink" href="#">auck</a></li>
                <li><a id = "peojectslink" href="#">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a id = "resumelink" href="#">Resume</a></li>
                <li><a id = "contactlink" href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div id="content">
            <div class="" id="about">
                <p class="header">uck</p>
                <p class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="sections"id="projects">
                <p class = "header">Projects</p>
                <p class="info">Projects</p>
            </div>
            <div class="sections" id="resume">
                <p class = "header">Resume</p>
                <p class="info">Resume</p>
            </div>
            <div class="sections" id="contacts">
                <p class = "header">Contact</p>
                <p class="info">Contact</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What does the html look like for where the contact link should be?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193414/scrolling-a-div-with-jquery

Comment: Is there a reason you're using jQuery instead of plain old anchors?

Comment: @James - That's not really a duplicate. This question scrolls a page to specific divs. That question scrolls a page by defined increments (irrespective of what divs are showing).

Comment: This is really good: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/. Worked for me.

Answer (score 360, accepted):

First, your code does not contain a `contact` div, it has a `contacts` div!

In sidebar you have `contact` in the div at the bottom of the page you have `contacts`. I removed the final `s` for the code sample. (you also misspelled the `projectslink` id in the sidebar).

Second, take a look at some of the examples for [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) on the jQuery reference page. You have to use click like, `object.click( function() { // Your code here } );` in order to bind a click event handler to the object.... Like in my example below. As an aside, you can also just trigger a click on an object by using it without arguments, like `object.click()`.

Third, `scrollTo` is a [plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) in jQuery. I don't know if you have the plugin installed. You can't use `scrollTo()` without the plugin. In this case, the functionality you desire is only 2 lines of code, so I see no reason to use the plugin.

Ok, now on to a solution.

The code below will scroll to the correct div if you click a link in the sidebar. The window does have to be big enough to allow scrolling:

```
// This is a functions that scrolls to #{blah}link
function goToByScroll(id) {
    // Remove "link" from the ID
    id = id.replace("link", "");
    // Scroll
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top
    }, 'slow');
}

$("#sidebar > ul > li > a").click(function(e) {
    // Prevent a page reload when a link is pressed
    e.preventDefault();
    // Call the scroll function
    goToByScroll(this.id);
});
```

[**Live Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/VPzxG/)

<strike>( Scroll to function taken from [here](http://djpate.com/2009/10/07/animated-scroll-to-anchorid-function-with-jquery/) )</strike>

---

PS: Obviously you should have a compelling reason to go this route instead of using anchor tags `<a href="#gohere">blah</a>` ... `<a name="gohere">blah title</a>`

Comment: Glad to know it helped, but I think you mean "pickle", though I find it's better to eat them than to get out of them.

Comment: It doesn't scroll at first click. :/ I click it second time and it works.

Comment: I think it's more logical to put the ID to the href like this: href="#about" 
http://jsfiddle.net/onigetoc/w5muyern/

Comment: it does not work at first time. but when we click 2nd time then its work perfectly.

Comment: thanks you so much for share solution here it save me time and get out from tension

Answer (score 120):

There is no `.scrollTo()` method in jQuery, but there is a `.scrollTop()` one. `.scrollTop` expects a parameter, that is, the pixel value where the scrollbar should scroll to.

Example:

```
$(window).scrollTop(200);
```

will scroll the window (if there is enough content in it).

So you can get this desired value with `.offset()` or `.position()`.

Example:

```
$(window).scrollTop($('#contact').offset().top);
```

This should scroll the `#contact` element into view.

The non-jQuery alternate method is `.scrollIntoView()`. You can call that method on any `DOM element` like:

```
$('#contact')[0].scrollIntoView(true);
```

`true` indicates that the element is positioned at the top whereas `false` would place it on the bottom of the view. The nice thing with the jQuery method is, you can even use it with `fx functions` like `.animate()`. So you might smooth scroll something.

Reference: [.scrollTop()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/), [.position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/), [.offset()](https://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still having similar problems.  The page loads scrolled down the page a certain amount, not the the contact div tho, and the link doesn't take me to the contact div either.  Thanks tho.  EDIT: say I'm spacing the divs out using top with css, would this cause it to go to the wrong place?  Just a thought.

Answer (score 22):

you can try :

```
$("#MediaPlayer").ready(function(){
    $("html, body").delay(2000).animate({
        scrollTop: $('#MediaPlayer').offset().top 
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 14):

Add this little function and use it as so: `$('div').scrollTo(500);`

```
jQuery.fn.extend(
{
  scrollTo : function(speed, easing)
  {
    return this.each(function()
    {
      var targetOffset = $(this).offset().top;
      $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, speed, easing);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

OK guys, this is a small solution, but it works fine.

suppose the following code:

```
<div id='the_div_holder' style='height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll'>
  <div class='post'>1st post</div>
  <div class='post'>2nd post</div>
  <div class='post'>3rd post</div>
</div>
```

you want when a new post is added to 'the_div_holder' then it scrolls its inner content (the div's .post) to the last one like a chat. So, do the following whenever a new .post is added to the main div holder:

```
var scroll = function(div) {
    var totalHeight = 0;
    div.find('.post').each(function(){
       totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
    });
    div.scrollTop(totalHeight);
  }
  // call it:
  scroll($('#the_div_holder'));
```

Answer (score 4):

First get the position of the div element upto which u want to scroll by jQuery position() method. 
 Example : *var pos = $("div").position();* 

 Then get the y cordinates (height) of that element with "**.top**" method. 
Example : pos.top; 
Then get the x cordinates of the that div element with "**.left**" method.
 These methods are originated from CSS positioning.
 Once we get x & y cordinates, then we can use javascript's **scrollTo();** method. 
This method scrolls the document upto specific height & width. 
It takes two parameters as x & y cordinates. Syntax :  **window.scrollTo(x,y);** 

 Then just pass the x & y cordinates of the DIV element in the **scrollTo()** function. 
 Refer the example below ↓ ↓

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Scroll upto Div with jQuery.
        </title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#button1").click(function () {
                    var x = $("#element").position(); //gets the position of the div element...
                    window.scrollTo(x.left, x.top); //window.scrollTo() scrolls the page upto certain position....
                    //it takes 2 parameters : (x axis cordinate, y axis cordinate);
                });
            });
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="button1">
            Click here to scroll
        </button>

        <div id="element" style="position:absolute;top:200%;left:0%;background-color:orange;height:100px;width:200px;">
            The DIV element.
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: And hay add some text explanation of what you did, just the does not make much sense..!!

Comment: As @ClainDsilva said, please add some textual explanation.

Answer (score -1):

No need too these.
Just simply add **div id** to **href of a < a > tag**

```
<li><a id = "aboutlink" href="#about">auck</a></li>
```

Just like that.

Comment: Please, throw more light on this. It didn't work for me.