# focus on page scroll navigation when using iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-plugins, scroll, focus

I've used Page Scroller Lite http://pagescroller.com to set up a single-page site at http://www.thestitchshop.co.uk

There seems to be an issue that scolling works only once when clicking on a menu item. It will only work again after one touched scrolls the page 'manually' by sliding the finger across the page.

Apparently, the issue is that the content gets the focus after the scroll and tapping on navigation then actually taps behind it.

I've tried contacting the author of pagecroller, but no luck.

So, how do I fix it? I don't have any JS knowledge, so I need a little more help along the way. Many thanks.

By the way,I've posted the same question here http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?886838-Problem-with-page-scrolling-on-iPad and I've tried adding the suggested code somehow, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

Well first I would say that since you are posting a question regarding a mobile device you should always provide what OS version you are running. It can make the difference between something working and something not being supported.

That being said, I tested the your implementation of this plugin on both iPhone and iPad running iOS 6 and it worked fine. For something as simple as a page scroll you don't really need to use a plug-in as jQuery itself can do this heavy lifting out of the box. See this post - [Scroll to a div using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432656/scroll-to-a-div-using-jquery)