# Open page at top even if there is an #anchor to lower down the page in the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a query: is it possible to disabled browsers default action on links such as [this example](http://example.com/page.html#part-123)?

I am not talking about disabling click event on Anchor tag( PART 123) using `event.preventDefault()`

What I am trying to do :
There is TOC at the beginning of page with name links (#part-) to different part of page. I can easily disable click event on each link using :

```
$("a.namedLink").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  //and do whatever I want to, like animated scroll then moving the dock-able header using jQuery Affix plugin
});
```

But, if someone copies the link or directly opens it by using the URL itself ([link](http://example.com/page.html#part-123)), the code above won't work because nothing has been clicked.

I've checked couple of examples, but, they all talk about same page and #click event, like this Stackoverflow thread [Scroll to a div using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432656/scroll-to-a-div-using-jquery) and others:

[link1](http://webdeveloperswall.com/javascript/scrolling-to-different-areas-on-same-page)

[link2](http://css-plus.com/2010/11/create-a-scrolling-anchor-link-with-jquery/)

Please let me know if we can do it and more importantly, if we should do it.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe bind something to the page load event and check the url for the hash?

Comment: If you don't want the window to be scrolled, find and remove `id="part-123"` from the markup.

Answer (score 2):

You can scroll to an anchor point using:

```
$(document).scrollTo("a[name='namedLink']");
```

You can also check the hash location on page load if the user hits the page directly with a hash:

```
$(function() {
  var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1, window.location.hash.length);
  if(hash != "") {
    $(document).scrollTo("a[name='"+hash+"']");
  }
});
```

**Should you?** It's entirely up to you. It would be like re-inventing the wheel just to make it red, even though not everyone likes red.

As pointed out, the very useful scrollTo() method is actually a plugin and not built into jQuery. It can be found here: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: I think `scrollTo` is a standalone plugin, that doesn't come with jQuery. If so, you should mention that.

Comment: @PavloMykhalov Good point, updated answer to reflect this

Comment: Thanks @Blade0rz, let me try a poc with what you are suggesting, but, I think http://flesler.com/jquery/localScroll/#section5c is somewhat closer to I need.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
$(function () {
  window.scrollTo(0,0);
});
```

to bring the user back to the top after the page has loaded. This will potentially mean the page jumps twice, however.