# Smooth scroll to specific div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is make it so that if you click on a button, it scrolls down (smoothly) to a specific div on the page.

What I need is if you click on the button, it smooth scrolls to the div 'second'.

```css
.first {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background: #ccc;
}

.second {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"><button type="button">Click Me!</button></div>
<div class="second">Hi</div>
```

Comment: You could try [this plugin](https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll) Although, [this one](http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/quick-guide-adding-smooth-scrolling-to-your-webpages/) is far more user friendly. You pretty much just have to link the JS file in the header, and change your markup appropriately for it to work.

Comment: this should help you:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432656/scroll-to-a-div-using-jquery

Answer (score 205, accepted):

do:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".second").offset().top},
        'slow');
});
```

Updated [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryXFt/3/)

Comment: Are you using javaScript here or jQuery?

Comment: @FahadUddin its jQuery.

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti: Why doesn't the JsFiddle has included the jquery library for it on that page?

Comment: @Sudhir Bastakoti but many users complaint that it's not smooth scrolling.

Answer (score 55):

There are many examples of smooth scrolling using JS libraries like jQuery, Mootools, Prototype, etc.

The following example is on pure JavaScript. If you have no jQuery/Mootools/Prototype on page or you don't want to overload page with heavy JS libraries the example will be of help.

http://jsfiddle.net/rjSfP/

HTML Part:

```
<div class="first"><button type="button" onclick="smoothScroll(document.getElementById('second'))">Click Me!</button></div>
<div class="second" id="second">Hi</div>
```

CSS Part:

```
.first {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background: #ccc;
}

.second {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background: #999;
}
```

JS Part:

```
window.smoothScroll = function(target) {
    var scrollContainer = target;
    do { //find scroll container
        scrollContainer = scrollContainer.parentNode;
        if (!scrollContainer) return;
        scrollContainer.scrollTop += 1;
    } while (scrollContainer.scrollTop == 0);

    var targetY = 0;
    do { //find the top of target relatively to the container
        if (target == scrollContainer) break;
        targetY += target.offsetTop;
    } while (target = target.offsetParent);

    scroll = function(c, a, b, i) {
        i++; if (i > 30) return;
        c.scrollTop = a + (b - a) / 30 * i;
        setTimeout(function(){ scroll(c, a, b, i); }, 20);
    }
    // start scrolling
    scroll(scrollContainer, scrollContainer.scrollTop, targetY, 0);
}
```

Comment: I am using this and it works great. How do I make the scroll slower though?

Comment: Any idea how to add offset for fixed navbar in this code? Here is example I made [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjSfP/93/)

Comment: Still helpfull after 5 years

Comment: Still helpful after 7 years 11 months with a ease property added

Comment: Still helpful after 8 years 5 months

Answer (score 34):

What if u use scrollIntoView function?

```
var elmntToView = document.getElementById("sectionId");
elmntToView.scrollIntoView();
```

Has {behavior: "smooth"} too.... ;) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Answer (score 12):

I played around with nico's answer a little and it felt jumpy. Did a bit of investigation and found `window.requestAnimationFrame` which is a function that is called on each repaint cycle. This allows for a more clean-looking animation. Still trying to hone in on good default values for step size but for my example things look pretty good using this implementation.

```
var smoothScroll = function(elementId) {
    var MIN_PIXELS_PER_STEP = 16;
    var MAX_SCROLL_STEPS = 30;
    var target = document.getElementById(elementId);
    var scrollContainer = target;
    do {
        scrollContainer = scrollContainer.parentNode;
        if (!scrollContainer) return;
        scrollContainer.scrollTop += 1;
    } while (scrollContainer.scrollTop == 0);

    var targetY = 0;
    do {
        if (target == scrollContainer) break;
        targetY += target.offsetTop;
    } while (target = target.offsetParent);

    var pixelsPerStep = Math.max(MIN_PIXELS_PER_STEP,
                                 (targetY - scrollContainer.scrollTop) / MAX_SCROLL_STEPS);

    var stepFunc = function() {
        scrollContainer.scrollTop =
            Math.min(targetY, pixelsPerStep + scrollContainer.scrollTop);

        if (scrollContainer.scrollTop >= targetY) {
            return;
        }

        window.requestAnimationFrame(stepFunc);
    };

    window.requestAnimationFrame(stepFunc);
}
```

Comment: @Alfonso See above. This is simply an optimized version of nico's code in a previous answer.

Comment: @NedRockson Doesn't work for me gives console message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null" but nico's code is working, What should I do so can apply clean animation ?

Comment: @KartikWatwani That means that on the line reading `scrollContainer = scrollContainer.parentNode`, scrollContainer is null. This likely means that you are not passing the correct `elementId` when calling this function. It's also possible that you are running this script on a page where that elementId does not exist.

Comment: @NedRockson If `elementId` would have been wrong I would have received the same error in case of @nico 's example but in that case scrolling is working but not smoothly.

Comment: Using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout` is the way to go. `setTimeout` shouldn't be use for animations.

Comment: This solution is awesome and has performances in mind, thank you!
Also, consider `window.smoothScroll = …` at the beginning instead of `var smoothScroll = …`.

Comment: For anyone running into the "parentNode of null" error as mentioned by Kartik Watwani, just be aware that for Ned's solution you just pass the element's ID to the smoothScroll function, whereas with nico's solution you pass the element itself.

Comment: Can confirm this works in 2022

Answer (score 8):

You can use basic css to achieve smooth scroll

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The solution that worked for me:

```
var element = document.getElementById("box");

element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
```

You can explore more options [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Answer (score 2):

I took the [Ned Rockson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1327710/ned-rockson)'s version and adjusted it to allow upwards scrolls as well.

```
var smoothScroll = function(elementId) {
  var MIN_PIXELS_PER_STEP = 16;
  var MAX_SCROLL_STEPS = 30;
  var target = document.getElementById(elementId);
  var scrollContainer = target;
  do {
    scrollContainer = scrollContainer.parentNode;
    if (!scrollContainer) return;
    scrollContainer.scrollTop += 1;
  } while (scrollContainer.scrollTop === 0);

  var targetY = 0;
  do {
    if (target === scrollContainer) break;
    targetY += target.offsetTop;
  } while (target = target.offsetParent);

  var pixelsPerStep = Math.max(MIN_PIXELS_PER_STEP,
    Math.abs(targetY - scrollContainer.scrollTop) / MAX_SCROLL_STEPS);

  var isUp = targetY < scrollContainer.scrollTop;

  var stepFunc = function() {
    if (isUp) {
      scrollContainer.scrollTop = Math.max(targetY, scrollContainer.scrollTop - pixelsPerStep);
      if (scrollContainer.scrollTop <= targetY) {
        return;
      }
    } else {
        scrollContainer.scrollTop = Math.min(targetY, scrollContainer.scrollTop + pixelsPerStep);

      if (scrollContainer.scrollTop >= targetY) {
        return;
      }
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(stepFunc);
  };

  window.requestAnimationFrame(stepFunc);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Ned Rockson basically answers this question. However there is a fatal flaw within his solution. When the targeted element is closer to the bottom of the page than the viewport-height, the function doesn't reach its exit statement and traps the user on the bottom of the page. This is simply solved by limiting the iteration count.

```
var smoothScroll = function(elementId) {
    var MIN_PIXELS_PER_STEP = 16;
    var MAX_SCROLL_STEPS = 30;
    var target = document.getElementById(elementId);
    var scrollContainer = target;
    do {
        scrollContainer = scrollContainer.parentNode;
        if (!scrollContainer) return;
        scrollContainer.scrollTop += 1;
    } while (scrollContainer.scrollTop == 0);

    var targetY = 0;
    do {
        if (target == scrollContainer) break;
        targetY += target.offsetTop;
    } while (target = target.offsetParent);

    var pixelsPerStep = Math.max(MIN_PIXELS_PER_STEP,
                                 (targetY - scrollContainer.scrollTop) / MAX_SCROLL_STEPS);

    var iterations = 0;
    var stepFunc = function() {
        if(iterations > MAX_SCROLL_STEPS){
            return;
        }
        scrollContainer.scrollTop =
            Math.min(targetY, pixelsPerStep + scrollContainer.scrollTop);

        if (scrollContainer.scrollTop >= targetY) {
            return;
        }

        window.requestAnimationFrame(stepFunc);
    };

    window.requestAnimationFrame(stepFunc);
}
```

Comment: Does the if statement with the following comparison, iterations > MAX_SCROLL_STEPS, even occur? The comparison is always returns false as iterations is initially set to 0 and never changes. Similarly, MAX_SCROLL_STEPS never changes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer for 2024. Same answer like Jyoti Duhan do, just giving heads up:

```
const appointmenbuttonlearnmore = document.getElementById('appointmenbuttonlearnmore');

appointmenbuttonlearnmore.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const appointmentFullElement = document.getElementById('appointmentfull');
    
    if (appointmentFullElement) {
        appointmentFullElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
});
```