# Read Less Button scroll page

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, scroll

I have a Read More/Read Less button for product descriptions on my website.

My problem is, at the bottom of the extended description, when clicking the Read Less button, it shortens the description as expected but the page doesn't scroll back up to the top of the description div so I'm left looking at the page footer.

Is there a way to make it scroll back up to the top of the div?

Comment: did you try a simple link with an anchor ?

Comment: I did, yeah, but to no avail. Perhaps it's JS is interfering somehow? The website is [here](http://radshaperc.businesscatalyst.com/scale-and-off-road/scale-rock-crawling-kits/1-10-gs01-komodo-truck-scale-crawler-kit#product-description)

Comment: Did you try [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18071046/smooth-scroll-to-specific-div-on-click) or [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor-using-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: That first post was the one! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers, this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryXFt/3/) has a script that works perfectly.

**The HTML**

```
<div class="first"><button type="button">Click Me!</button></div>
<div class="second">Hi</div>
```

**The JavaScript**

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".second").offset().top},
        'slow');
});
```

**The CSS**

```
.first {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background: #ccc;
}

.second {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background: #999;
}
```