# Smooth scroll to specific div when clicking a span element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

I'm pretty new to all of this, so I might just be missing something. However, I'm trying to create an arrow at the bottom of my webpage the then scrolls to the div below it. I read this post [Smooth scroll to specific div on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18071046/smooth-scroll-to-specific-div-on-click) but couldn't get it to work for me. I started a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ConnorBetts/ua4z6x7n/2/ (the black box is a place holder for the arrow.)

Here's what I have...

HTML:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: white;
  font-family: stevie-sans, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

#homehero {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(130deg, rgb(249, 204, 0) 0%, rgb(249, 185, 60) 100%);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.homepage-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 13px;
  background: url("images/arrow.svg") no-repeat center center;
  background-color: #000;
  background-size: 50px 13px;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  filter: drop-shadow( 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3));
}

.bigdivlight {
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  color: #303030;
  max-width: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="homehero">
  <p id="hero-text">Test</p>
  <span href="#about" class="homepage-arrow" alt="arrow"></span>
</div>
<div id="about" class="bigdivlight">
  <h3>Hey,</h3>
  <p class="darktext">I'm some example text</p>
</div>
```

I am trying to have it work similar to [snapchat.com](http://snapchat.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add jQuery script:

```js
$(".homepage-arrow").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#about").offset().top},
        'slow');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: white;
  font-family: stevie-sans, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

#homehero {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(130deg, rgb(249, 204, 0) 0%, rgb(249, 185, 60) 100%);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.homepage-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 13px;
  background: url("images/arrow.svg") no-repeat center center;
  background-color: #000;
  background-size: 50px 13px;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  filter: drop-shadow( 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3));
}

.bigdivlight {
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  color: #303030;
  max-width: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="homehero">
  <p id="hero-text">Test</p>
  <span href="#about" class="homepage-arrow" alt="arrow"></span>
</div>
<div id="about" class="bigdivlight">
  <h3>Hey,</h3>
  <p class="darktext">I'm some example text</p>
</div>
```