# Smooth scroll isn't smooth at all; smooth scroll only scrolls a number of pixels and not to the specified div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to add an on-click-smooth-scroll effect like this one: https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

I have read this: [Smooth scroll to specific div on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18071046/smooth-scroll-to-specific-div-on-click) and I am unable to adapt it. I don't understand what `scrollTop: $("#page2").offset().top` does.

My **issue** is that the scroll is **"snapping"**. And that's probably because I have applied `scroll-snap` on the containers.

Also, when you're in-between the pages and **click** on the **scroll down arrow** it will **either move up or down**.

I would like to get the second page on full view whenever I press on that arrow. It should Scroll Down until `#page2` has `height: 100vh` or it occupies the whole view port.

```js
// eliminate scroll-bar
var child = document.getElementById('child-container');
child.style.right = child.clientWidth - child.offsetWidth + "px";

//scroll down effect on scroll-down-arrow
$(".scroll-down-arrow").click(function() {
    $('html,body,#child-container').animate({scrollTop: $("#page2").offset().top}, 'slow', 'linear');
});
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* *** index.html - START *** */

body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#parent-container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#child-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px; /* exact value is given through JavaScript */
    overflow: auto;
    scroll-snap-type: both proximity;
}

header {    
    height: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: bottom center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    scroll-snap-align: center;
}

header h1 {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: sticky;
    top: 5%;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

header p {
    position: sticky;
    width: 450px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

header .scroll-down-arrow {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 bottom: 20px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
 z-index: 100;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%) rotate(45deg);
    animation: fade_move_down 3s ease-in-out infinite;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*animated scroll arrow animation*/
@keyframes fade_move_down {
    0%   { transform:translate(0,-15px) rotate(45deg); opacity: 0;  }
    25%  {opacity: 1;}
    /* 50%  { opacity: 1;  } */
    100% { transform:translate(0,10px) rotate(45deg); opacity: 0; }
  }

.container_page_2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-snap-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="parent-container">
        <div id="child-container">

            <!-- #header -->
            <header>
                <div class="nav-container">
                    <ul>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <a href="#page2"><h1 id="sticky-title">Lorem ipsum</h1></a>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi debitis in libero tenetur suscipit iusto eum nulla dolorum aperiam adipisci unde veritatis vel iure, a nam, saepe exercitationem illum vitae.</p>
                <div class="scroll-down-arrow"></div>
            </header>

            <!-- #page2 -->
            <div id="page2" class="container_page_2">
                <div class="column active">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h1>1</h1>
                        <div class="box">
                            <h2>background-attachment: fixed;</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore necessitatibus possimus fuga voluptate incidunt enim eius sed, ad suscipit error quasi ex blanditiis ipsa, at vero officiis voluptatem a modi!                                
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bg bg1"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h1>2</h1>
                        <div class="box">
                            <h2>background-attachment: scroll;</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore necessitatibus possimus fuga voluptate incidunt enim eius sed, ad suscipit error quasi ex blanditiis ipsa, at vero officiis voluptatem a modi!                                
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bg bg2"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h1>3</h1>
                        <div class="box">
                            <h2>background-attachment: scroll;</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore necessitatibus possimus fuga voluptate incidunt enim eius sed, ad suscipit error quasi ex blanditiis ipsa, at vero officiis voluptatem a modi!                                
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bg bg3"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h1>4</h1>
                        <div class="box">
                            <h2>background-attachment: fixed;</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore necessitatibus possimus fuga voluptate incidunt enim eius sed, ad suscipit error quasi ex blanditiis ipsa, at vero officiis voluptatem a modi!                                
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bg bg4"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

https://codepen.io/bleah1/pen/gjYBgQ

I haven't added all the elements from the second page, but it doesn't matter, because the scrolling isn't affected. As you can see it's not smooth at all, it's actually pretty snappy.

What do you think ? I would like to keep the scroll-snap, because I like that idea.

Answer (score 2):

Hi can you try this solution. 
Basically I removed the css when click event starts then added it when the scrollTop event ends.
Remember to remove it from your css `#child-container`

```
$(".scroll-down-arrow").click(function() {
  $('#child-container').css('scroll-snap-type','')
    $('html,body,#child-container').animate({
       scrollTop: $("#page2").offset().top}, 'slow', 'linear')
      .promise()
      .done(() => {$('#child-container')
      .css('scroll-snap-type','both proximity')
    });
});
```

Comment: That is half of the solution. This eliminates `scroll-snap` forever and only adds it after I click on the arrow. I think that we should eliminate `scroll-snap` on click, but before or after the smooth scroll it should still be active.

Comment: Also, if this code `$('#child-container').css('scroll-snap-type','');` is supposed to eliminate the `scroll-snap` on click, why do I have to remove `scroll-snap-type: both proximity;` from `#child-container` ?

Comment: It also doesn't fix the effect of scrolling up or down whenever you're in between pages.

Comment: I've fixed it. The trick to getting your answer to work is that `.css` will only remove the element's attributes defined in the "style" attribute. So, adding `scroll-snap-type: both proximity;` as `style` inside the HTML like this: `<div id="child-container" style="scroll-snap-type: both proximity;">` fixed all of the issues.

I think you should edit your answer and I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: Also, to fix the effect of scrolling up or down whenever you're in between pages I've replaced `scrollTop: $("#page2").offset().top` with `scrollTop: $(window).height()`. Don't ask me why it works, but it does.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Ekin Alcar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59395345/smooth-scroll-isnt-smooth-at-all-smooth-scroll-only-scrolls-a-number-of-pixels/59395833#59395833) I was able to fix my issue. I followed his idea of removing the `scroll-snap-type` css attribute from `#child-container` by using `$('#child-container').css('scroll-snap-type','');` inside of the original script, like this:

```
$(".scroll-down-arrow-container").click(function() {
    $('#child-container').css('scroll-snap-type','');
    $('html, body, #child-container').animate({
            scrollTop: $(window).height()
        }, 1000)
    .promise()
    .done(() => {$('#child-container')
        .css('scroll-snap-type','both proximity')
    });
});
```

The trick with `.css` is that it can only remove attributes that are used in the `style` tag inside a `.html` file. It won't work with a `.css` stylesheet.

From the [API's documentation](https://api.jquery.com/css/):

> It does not, however, remove a style that has been applied with a CSS rule in a stylesheet or < style > element.

As such `scroll-snap-type: both proximity;` was removed from the `.css` file and added in the `.html` file:

```
<div id="child-container" style="scroll-snap-type: both proximity;">
```

Also, to fix the effect of scrolling up or down whenever you're in between pages I've replaced `scrollTop: $("#page2").offset().top` with `scrollTop: $(window).height()`. Don't ask me why it works, but it does.