# how to move href using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, arrow-keys, location-href

sorry for my english.

Using jquery, i want pressing keyboard arrow key to redirect to an url with href(#g) tag

I mean if downkey is pressed, how to move to #g ?

Javascript :

```
$(function(e){
  $(e.witch==38)
    move #g
    //how to that?
    not use that window.location='#g';

});
```

html :

```
<div class="nav">
<input type="button" class="arrow leftarrow" value="left"/>
<input type="button" class="arrow downarrow" value="down"/>
<input type="button" class="arrow uparrow" value="up"/>
<input type="button" class="arrow rightarrow" value="right"/>

<a href="#a" id="aarrow">a</a>
<a href="#b" id="barrow">b</a>
<a href="#c" id="carrow">c</a>
<a href="#d" id="darrow">d</a>
<a href="#e" id="earrow">e</a>
<a href="#f" id="farrow">f</a>
<a href="#g" id="garrow">g</a>


<div id="a">
<p>a1</p>
<p>a2</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a1</p>
<p>a2</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
<p>a3</p>
</div>
<div id="b">
<p>b1</p>
<p>b2</p>
<p>b3</p>
<p>b1</p>
<p>b2</p>
<p>b3</p>
<p>b1</p>
<p>b2</p>
<p>b3</p>
<p>b1</p>
<p>b2</p>
<p>b3</p>
<p>b1</p>
<p>b2</p>
<p>b3</p>
<p>b1</p>
<p>b2</p>
<p>b3</p>
<p>b1</p>
<p>b2</p>
<p>b3</p>
<p>b1</p>
<p>b2</p>
<p>b3</p>
<p>b1</p>
<p>b2</p>
<p>b3</p>
<p>b1</p>
<p>b2</p>
<p>b3</p>
</div>
<div id="c">
<p>c1</p>
<p>c2</p>
<p>c3</p>
<p>c1</p>
<p>c2</p>
<p>c3</p>
<p>c1</p>
<p>c2</p>
<p>c3</p>
<p>c1</p>
<p>c2</p>
<p>c3</p>
<p>c1</p>
<p>c2</p>
<p>c3</p>
<p>c1</p>
<p>c2</p>
<p>c3</p>
<p>c1</p>
<p>c2</p>
<p>c3</p>
<p>c1</p>
<p>c2</p>
<p>c3</p>
<p>c1</p>
<p>c2</p>
<p>c3</p>
<p>c1</p>
<p>c2</p>
<p>c3</p>
<p>c1</p>
<p>c2</p>
<p>c3</p>
<p>c1</p>
<p>c2</p>
<p>c3</p>
<p>c1</p>
<p>c2</p>
<p>c3</p>
<p>c1</p>
<p>c2</p>
<p>c3</p>
</div>
<div id="d">
<p>d1</p>
<p>d2</p>
<p>d3</p>
<p>d1</p>
<p>d2</p>
<p>d3</p>
<p>d1</p>
<p>d2</p>
<p>d3</p>
<p>d1</p>
<p>d2</p>
<p>d3</p>
<p>d1</p>
<p>d2</p>
<p>d3</p>
<p>d1</p>
<p>d2</p>
<p>d3</p>
<p>d1</p>
<p>d2</p>
<p>d3</p>
<p>d1</p>
<p>d2</p>
<p>d3</p>
<p>d1</p>
<p>d2</p>
<p>d3</p>
<p>d1</p>
<p>d2</p>
<p>d3</p>
<p>d1</p>
<p>d2</p>
<p>d3</p>
<p>d1</p>
<p>d2</p>
<p>d3</p>
<p>d1</p>
<p>d2</p>
<p>d3</p>
</div>
<div id="e">
<p>e1</p>
<p>e2</p>
<p>e3</p>
<p>e1</p>
<p>e2</p>
<p>e3</p>
<p>e1</p>
<p>e2</p>
<p>e3</p>
<p>e1</p>
<p>e2</p>
<p>e3</p>
<p>e1</p>
<p>e2</p>
<p>e3</p>
<p>e1</p>
<p>e2</p>
<p>e3</p>
<p>e1</p>
<p>e2</p>
<p>e3</p>
<p>e1</p>
<p>e2</p>
<p>e3</p>
<p>e1</p>
<p>e2</p>
<p>e3</p>
<p>e1</p>
<p>e2</p>
<p>e3</p>
<p>e1</p>
<p>e2</p>
<p>e3</p>
<p>e1</p>
<p>e2</p>
<p>e3</p>
<p>e1</p>
<p>e2</p>
<p>e3</p>
<p>e1</p>
<p>e2</p>
<p>e3</p>
</div>
<div id="f">
<p>f1</p>
<p>f2</p>
<p>f3</p>
<p>f1</p>
<p>f2</p>
<p>f3</p>
<p>f1</p>
<p>f2</p>
<p>f3</p>
<p>f1</p>
<p>f2</p>
<p>f3</p>
<p>f1</p>
<p>f2</p>
<p>f3</p>
<p>f1</p>
<p>f2</p>
<p>f3</p>
<p>f1</p>
<p>f2</p>
<p>f3</p>
<p>f1</p>
<p>f2</p>
<p>f3</p>
<p>f1</p>
<p>f2</p>
<p>f3</p>
<p>f1</p>
<p>f2</p>
<p>f3</p>
<p>f1</p>
<p>f2</p>
<p>f3</p>
<p>f1</p>
<p>f2</p>
<p>f3</p>
<p>f1</p>
<p>f2</p>
<p>f3</p>
<p>f1</p>
<p>f2</p>
<p>f3</p>
</div>
<div id="g">
<p>g1</p>
<p>g2</p>
<p>3g</p>
<p>g1</p>
<p>g2</p>
<p>3g</p>
<p>g1</p>
<p>g2</p>
<p>3g</p>
<p>g1</p>
<p>g2</p>
<p>3g</p>
<p>g1</p>
<p>g2</p>
<p>3g</p>
<p>g1</p>
<p>g2</p>
<p>3g</p>
<p>g1</p>
<p>g2</p>
<p>3g</p>
<p>g1</p>
<p>g2</p>
<p>3g</p>
<p>g1</p>
<p>g2</p>
<p>3g</p>
<p>g1</p>
<p>g2</p>
<p>3g</p>
<p>g1</p>
<p>g2</p>
<p>3g</p>
<p>g1</p>
<p>g2</p>
<p>3g</p>
<p>g1</p>
<p>g2</p>
<p>3g</p>
<p>g1</p>
<p>g2</p>
<p>3g</p>
<p>g1</p>
<p>g2</p>
<p>3g</p>
</div>


</div>
```

Comment: Why "not use that window.location='#g'?

Comment: This code might not work because of a simple typo: `witch` and `which` sound the same, but are very different words.

Comment: you want this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432656/scroll-to-a-div-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).bind('keydown',function(e){
    console.log('key down');
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    if(e.keyCode === 38)
    {
       console.log('key 38');
       $('#g')[0].scrollIntoView(true);
       e.preventDefault(); 
    }
});
```

the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/BZehV/

Answer (score 0):

You can type the following jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).bind('keydown',function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 38){
      $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#g").offset().top}, 1000); 
    }
  });
});
```

OR you can build your own plugin, to use it everywhere you want:
create a file and rename it to *jquery.goto.js* , then type:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.goTo = function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top + 'px'
        }, 'fast');
        return this; // for chaining...
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Now to use your plugin include it to your page

```
<script src="js/jquery.goto.js"></script>
```

to scroll to some element:

```
$('#g').goTo();
```

That's it, Good luck