# Scroll down to exact div on the same page without refreshing after clicking a link

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with lots of contents, I want to put a hyperlink in the top, that scrolls the page to a `div` .
this is my code :

```
        <a id = "show" class="show" href="#" onclick="return toggleOptions(this);"><h2>FIRST BUTTON</h2></a>
        <div id="toggleOptions" class="toggleOptions"> // this is div which is somewhere in center of page
        text text text....
        more text text.... 
        text text.........
        </div>
```

I know that I need to use JavaScript, something like that:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.location = "/index.php#myDiv";
</script>
```

Just don't know how to do It correctly. Please help me .

Comment: `<a href="#myDiv">My Div</a >`

Comment: http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks08.htm

Comment: You can do this with jquery. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432656/scroll-to-a-div-using-jquery)

Comment: dont you want to accept an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

No need to javascript, simply do this :

```
   <a id = "show" class="show" href="#toggleOptions"><h2>FIRST BUTTON</h2></a>
    <div id="toggleOptions" class="toggleOptions"> 
    text text text..
    more text text.. 
    text text.......
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that much easier that I though.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<a href="#idOfDiv">Go to my div</a>

<div id="idOfDiv">...</div>
```

Comment: What if I'd like to go 50px above that div? Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
<a id = "show" class="show" href="#toggleOptions"><h2>BUTTON</h2></a>
    <div id="toggleOptions" class="toggleOptions"> 
    text    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need of having javascript for this. Just use the href of  tag as follows:

```
    <a href="#toggleOptions">
```

Where #toogleOptions is the id of your target divs.

Comment: I'd like to go 50px above that div! Is there any option to do that?