# youtube video iframe onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube

I'm trying to load the yt video by clicking on the link but I need two actions to happen.
The problem is that I can't execute both action only one. Is there a way to do it?

```
<a href="tS8392pvFIw">Windows Phone</a>  //this works
<a href="#video">Windows Phone</a> // but I also need this anchor to execute
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<a href="#video" onclick="tS8392pvFIw">Windows Phone</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a new function that do those two actions.
Make a new listener in jquery for this link, pass the event with it and do a `event.preventDefault()` to avoid href action. Then execute your `"tS8392pvFIw"` and then use this function to go to your element with your id:

```
function goToByScroll(id){
      // Remove "link" from the ID
    id = id.replace("link", "");
      // Scroll
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},
        'slow');
}
```

I took this code in this question: [scroll to a div using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432656/scroll-to-a-div-using-jquery)
Take a look.

Comment: the anchor is actually for the tab not for scrolling down to a specific place. I tried to create an function but it doesn't work for the YT video embed.

Comment: Do you have more code to show? What the code of the iframe? You want to open a new tab with the video inside?