# how to scroll to a position in a page by clicking on link

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, css, scroll

Hi coder i am new to **jquery**. i serach alot but fail to find this what i am looking is not a customize application, i just want process or method how we can achieve this.

Suppose i have a menu or link like below

> - Home
> - About
> - Contact

As a link or menu and when i click on that any of the link or menu i **srcoll** down to position of the page where details for it present..

> Just like [This link](http://www.ikf.co.in/advertising-media.html#Baring-our-Soul) where click on the above menu scroll to the
>   position of it on the page

This should be a single page application.

Any idea's or tutorial for this i want to do it jquery.

I can use scrollup(), scroll(), animate() but how to proceed this that is the main concren any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432656/scroll-to-a-div-using-jquery

Comment: `<a href="#somediv">test</a>` and you don't need jquery :)

Comment: Thank let me look at it and if this is want i want then i will let you know my friend thank for the link

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple jQuery scroll to anchor up or down the page...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579643/simple-jquery-scroll-to-anchor-up-or-down-the-page)

Comment: try to search for Parallax Scrolling websites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best link for your solution
 [Single Page Site with Smooth Scrolling, Highlighted Link, and Fixed Navigation](http://www.callmenick.com/2013/04/22/single-page-site-with-smooth-scrolling-highlighted-link-and-fixed-navigation/)

In this link you get how to stick your menu using this

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
        var window_top = $(window).scrollTop()+12; // the "12" should equal the margin-top value for nav.stick
        var div_top = $('#nav-anchor').offset().top;
        if (window_top > div_top) {
            $('nav').addClass('stick');
        } else {
            $('nav').removeClass('stick');
        }
    });
```

use scrollto.js file to scroll through the page and call it in that function for smooth scrolling

```
 $("nav a").click(function (evn) {
        evn.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').scrollTo(this.hash, this.hash);
    });
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 2):

Are you by any chance talking about HTML anchors?
http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks08.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#scrollToId').offset().top});
```

Check this solution [jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035)

Comment: in this button is at the bottom what i want is to to put button at top and then move to element