# Smoothscroll bounces up and down on different anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this problem with smooth scrolling on my website, where the script scrolls down to the `<div>`, but if you click the same `<div>` or any other `<div>`, it doesn't seem to understand where the next `<div>` is. Instead, it'll just bounce up and down around the same kind of area it was just at.

[This](http://www.ico.mmu.ac.uk/13143651/dip/pages/football.html) is the website in question.

The script I'm using:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('a[href^="#"]').click(function(e) {

        jQuery('#main').animate(
            {
                scrollTop: jQuery(this.hash).offset().top - 50
            }, 1000);

        return false;

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

This will work fine only if I click the link when I'm at the top of the page, but won't work at all if it's from one link straight to the other.

Could someone have a look at the website and attempt to fix this please? As I'm a little out my depth with JavaScript.

Thank you.

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me, can't replicate the issue?

Comment: Click one of the sidebar links twice in a row, it'll bounce from where it is back up to the top. And if i try going from one div to another it just doesn't really move

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/3432718/1181310

Comment: Thanks, but i've just tried what was suggested and all it seemed to do was stop it from working all together, i'm sure it's a matter of misslinking stuff up, but i'm no good with javascript to really know what it might be.

Comment: On a sidenote, `return false;` returns (closes) the function, so the `e.preventDefault()` is never going to run. I'd suggest moving it to a line above the `return` statement.