# Scrolling to a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question that was answered before probably, but I was not able to make a code work.

I have an `<a href="#page-contact">`, and once the user click on it, it should scroll down (with animation) to a div with id `"page-contact"`. It does take me to the form but with no animation

Here is the code:

```
<li class=""><a href="#page-contact">Contact</a></li>


<section id="page-contact" class="page-contact">
</section>

 $('.page-contact').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(this.href);
    if( target.length ) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#page-contact").offset().top
    }, "slow");
  }
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432656/scroll-to-a-div-using-jquery

Comment: "but with no animation" means the jQuery code snippet actually fails and what you get is the default behavior of the browser.

Comment: change `var target = $(this.href);` to `var target = this.href;` then the code should work

Comment: no, still the same issue :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually something really small..

```
$('.page-contact').on('click', function(event) {
     //..
};
```

You connect this to a click on the target div, not the button.
Connect to event to a class that your button has and it will work.

```
$('#scrollButton').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(this.hash);
    if( target.length ) {
        event.preventDefault();    
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, "slow");
    }
});
```

Fiddle to try out: http://jsfiddle.net/Macavity/xeqmnoLL/2/

Answer (score 1):

One reason is `href` property returns the absolute path of the anchor, i.e. `"http://www.example.com#hash"`. As jQuery can't find the target element the `length` of the collection is `0` and the `if` block is not executed.

Either use `this.getAttribute('href')` which returns the original `href` *attribute* or the `hash` property that returns hash segment of the `href` attribute instead of the `href` *property*.

```
var target = $(this.hash); // $('#page-contact')
```

Also note that your click handler is bound to the *target* `section` element not the `a` element.

```
$('li a').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(this.hash);
    if( target.length ) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, "slow");
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(this.href)` not valid selector so `target` variable always empty, change var `target = $(this.href);` to `var target = this.href;` to get link

`$(this.href)` seletor work as.

```
$("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515247/scrolling-to-a-div-using-jquery#29515468")
```

### > Object[]

```
 $('.page-contact').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = this.href;
    if( target.length ) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#page-contact").offset().top
    }, "slow");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong, change to this:

```
$('a[href="#page-contact"]').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = this.getAttribute("href");
    if($(target).length) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $("#page-contact").offset().top
       }, "slow");
    }
});
```