# How to focus on a div that has just appeared?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this component:

```js
$chevron.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.disclaimer-wrapper').slideDown('fast', function() {
    $(this).focus();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="footer">
  <div class="disclaimer-wrapper"> //this div is hidden Hidden Content
  </div>
</section>
```

I am trying to click on an anchor (`$chevron`) and then display the element `.disclaimer-wrapper` but the document is not focusing or scrolling down to that element when it appears so the user can't see the new content being displayed.

What am I missing?

Comment: `$.focus()` I don't think that means what you think it means. https://api.jquery.com/focus/ what do you mean focus on it? You want the browser to scroll so that element's in view?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll to a div using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432656/scroll-to-a-div-using-jquery)

Comment: chevron is id or class,selector is correct?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Focus does not work on divs, however there is a workaround to that, in simple words, you need to set the tab index of div to -1, like this:

```js
$('#chevron').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.disclaimer-wrapper').slideDown('fast', function() {
    $(this).attr("tabindex", -1).focus();
  });
});
```

```css
.disclaimer-wrapper {
  display: none;
}

.disclaimer-wrapper:focus {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="footer">
  <a href="#" id="chevron">click</a>
  <div class="disclaimer-wrapper"> //this div is hidden Hidden Content
  </div>
</section>
```

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/61wd9h5v/1/) of it, you can check it out.

Comment: The answer is not fully correct. It is possible to focus on div as long as the div has `contentEditable` attribute

Comment: According to the jQuery focus docs https://api.jquery.com/focus/, tab index is the way to make focus function work on a div, not contentEditable property.

Comment: Perhaps, I don't work with jQuery, but you said: *jQuery Focus does not work on divs*, and jQuery, is JavaScript. and when div has `contentEditable`, you can focus it, so you can do the exact same thing (at least I think so) with jQuery.