# Can I scroll to page section without using hash(#) method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been using '#' in 'href' with distinct div ids that are to be scrolled to.

But I came across a problem where I can't use # in my URL. Are there any other approaches to solve it?

Comment: Google for "jQuery animate scrollTop"

Comment: its not about scroll page to top. Rather, its about scrolling to different sections of page controlled by navigation Menu.

Comment: why downvote? he just asking, relax. @AtuleshChandraKarna just google scrolltop, it does exactly what you ask for

Comment: Did you google it ?

Comment: yeah I did, it showed results related about using ids for different sections and controlling them using href from anchor tag. But, my problem is I cant use it inside my projects. I am in search for different approach.

Comment: You can get the element to scroll to by any jQuery selector...

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov https://jsfiddle.net/q3vnfqam/ please have a look at it, I want something like this in another approach

Comment: This fiddler doesn't work for me..

Comment: Hey, I think.. I got the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432656/scroll-to-a-div-using-jquery @EvgenyKolyakov thank you for your time.

Comment: Most welcome, sorry I'm short with words:)

Comment: The fiddler works just fine, just won't show any results when all the anchors are visible in view. Updated the fiddler with more text, so it's more visible. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/q3vnfqam/1/)

Comment: thank you for your help @sankorati

Answer (score 1):

The plugin jQuery.scrollTo is what you want :

https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo