# How to add some parameter and hash(#) id in url jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function loadThisUrl(yr){
    if ('URLSearchParams' in window) {
        var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        searchParams.set("get_of_year", yr);

        window.location.search = searchParams.toString();
        //window.location.hash="yeartabwrapper";
    }
}
```

This code generates the url like:

```
http://localhost/gipfipan/pedagogical-action/update?id=5&get_of_year=2017
```

and I want like below url:

```
http://localhost/gipfipan/pedagogical-action/update?id=5&get_of_year=2017/#yeartabwrapper
```

Comment: you want to recover the `id` parameter??

Comment: No, I want to add a div id in url with hash, to redirect that page in that div.
Thanks

Comment: If you want to scroll  to a div, you can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432656/scroll-to-a-div-using-jquery

Comment: You do know that the part of URL after hash will not be sent to the server, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do assign the hash before search it will work

```
function loadThisUrl(yr){
    if ('URLSearchParams' in window) {
        var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        searchParams.set("get_of_year", yr);
        window.location.hash="yeartabwrapper";
        window.location.search = searchParams.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, hash have to add before the search parameter.