# scrollTo not scrolling to correct position react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to scroll to a certain element in a react application, an empty div that sits on the end of the page. I'm trying to achieve this by using a Ref to track the div, and inside a useEffect() calling scrollTo on the div. Unfortunately it's not scrolling to the correct position - it should end up at the bottom of the page, but it only ends up part way down.

I have my suspicions why this is the case - an API call is made to receive data and populate a list, and I think it is scrolling to the point before the list is populated and thus makes the page bigger. What I don't get is that I have placed the scrolling code in a useEffect where the second parameter is the list state, so this should run *after* the list is populated. I've also tried replacing useEffect with useLayoutEffect but to no avail. The only thing I can think of is putting the scrolling code in a timer, but that seems atrocious. Am I missing something?

Simplified Example

```
const [messages, setMessages] = React.useState<string[]>([])
const endOfPageRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

useEffect(() => {
    apiCall().then(result => setMessages(result))
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    endOfPageRef.current?.scrollTo();
}, [messages])

return(
    <div className="root">
        <MessageList messages={messages}></MessageList>
        <div ref={endOfPageRef}></div>
    </div>
);
```

As stated previously, this ends up scrolling about a quarter way down the screen instead the desired behavior of to the bottom.

Comment: scrollTo(), expects x and y cordinates.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo

Comment: I think this will help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432656/scroll-to-a-div-using-jquery. I meant the idea. Please don't copy-paste Jquery in react.

Comment: @SanishJoseph I can enter 0, 100000 in the scrollTo and it still won't scroll to the bottom. The problem is that the react list is loading *after* the scroll has happened.