# Make div content go up inside parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, chat

I need to make a certain div contents to simulate a scroll, when new data is added, kind of like facebook chat. How do I go about this? I'm using jQuery.

Here's a markup sample :

```
<div id="chat-messages">
   <div class="msg">John Doe says : Hi!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to put a fixed height (`height: 400px`) on the container div (chat-messages) and a scroll(`overflow-y:scroll`) for vertical content to make the scroll appear.

Next, when a new message is posted, you need to scroll down using javascript.
For example:

```
$(".chat-messages").attr({ scrollTop: $(".chat-messages").attr("scrollHeight") });
```

Or animate the scroll:

```
$(".chat-messages").animate({ scrollTop: $("chat-messages").attr("scrollHeight") }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Solutions found similar to what you are describing:

- Load Data From Server While Scrolling Using jQuery AJAX: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239436/Load-Data-From-Server-While-Scrolling-Using-JQuery

There are some other solutions here:

- [Scrolling a div with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193414/scrolling-a-div-with-jquery)
- [jQuery Scroll to Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284814/jquery-scroll-to-div)
- [Scroll to a div using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432656/scroll-to-a-div-using-jquery)

Comment: @EvilP I didn't know this. Thanks for the pointer. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will append new content at the bottom of a div. I guess that's what you want.

```
$('#chat-messages').append(newdiv);
```

But I think you need to do a bit of background reading. [Check this out](http://www.gamexe.net/other/jquery-chatbox/).