# Manipulating a scrollable div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div with the following CSS properties, in order to have it scroll in place:

```
height: 746px;
width: 295px;
overflow: auto;
margin-bottom: 11px;
position: relative;
```

I need to do two seperate things with jQuery:

1. onclick of a button, scroll the box up by 100px.
2. upon reaching the bottom of the box when scrolling, fire a function.

I've tried using both `.position()` and `.offset()` to get where it is now, but neither are updating the position when it's scrolling. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193414/scrolling-a-div-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

1. use the scrollTop property

   $(element).scrollTop($(element).scrollTop()+100);
2. use the scroll event

   $(element).scroll(function(){
     //check the height of the div and the scrollTop value so you know if you are at the bottom and then do some code
   })