# How to bind the page's scroll bar to div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I bind the page's scroll bar to a particular div instead of the entire page. See Google Plus for an example of this functionality.!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ab82L.png

Comment: Go to Google Plus and Scroll down the page... You will see that div is scrolling... not a page

Comment: Try this answer maybe?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193414/scrolling-a-div-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [position fixed](http://davidwalsh.name/css-fixed-position) panels down the left and across the top. The body will still scroll as normal, but the panels on the sides will make it look like only part of the page is scrolling.

Comment: I alredy do that... but i have overlap another div, when i stretch my page lower than min-width

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with the browser's native scrollbar, you could always

1. Create a container
2. Set the height and width of the container to 100%
3. Set overflow to scroll (or auto)

That way you created your own viewport and have more control.

Comment: i have header div in a body and scroll bar not fully visible in container :(